# Append values into key pair from two lines

Tags: python, perl, bash

My text file out put looks like this on two lines:

```
DelayTimeThreshold|MaxDelayPerMinute|Name
10000|5|rca
```

My desired output is too look like this:

```
DelayTimeThreshold 10000
MaxDelayPerMinute 5
Name rca
```

I'm having no luck trying this:

```
sed '$!N;s/|/\n/' foo
```

Any advice would be welcomed, thank you.

Comment: You tagged it as python, yet you say want a solution via Bash or Perl - what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have just two lines, this can be a way:

```
$ paste -d' ' <(head -1 file | sed 's/|/\n/g') <(tail -1 file | sed 's/|/\n/g')
DelayTimeThreshold 10000
MaxDelayPerMinute 5
Name rca
```

By pieces. Let's get the first line and replace every pipe `|` with a new line:

```
$ head -1 file | sed 's/|/\n/g'
DelayTimeThreshold
MaxDelayPerMinute
Name
```

And do the same with the last line:

```
$ tail -1 file | sed 's/|/\n/g'
10000
5
rca
```

Then it is just a matter of pasting both results with a space as delimiter:

```
paste -d' ' output1 output2
```

Comment: I love your `paste` solution. `+1`. You could do it with no `head`/`tail` too, just with `sed`: `paste -d' ' <(sed -n '1s/|/\n/gp' file) <(sed -n '2s/|/\n/gp' file)`

Comment: Thanks, @gniourf_gniourf :) I like my version with `head` and `tail` and I am not familiar with `sed 1s/` but upvote your comment so people can see it easily when looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner would work for your requirement:

```
awk -F'|' '!f{gsub(/\||$/," %s\n");f=$0;next}{printf f,$1,$2,$3}' file
```

output:

```
kent$ echo "DelayTimeThreshold|MaxDelayPerMinute|Name
10000|5|rca"|awk -F'|' '!f{gsub(/\||$/," %s\n");f=$0;next}{printf f,$1,$2,$3}'  
DelayTimeThreshold 10000
MaxDelayPerMinute 5
Name rca
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Array::Transpose](http://search.cpan.org/~mrdvt/Array-Transpose-0.05/lib/Array/Transpose.pm) module:

```
perl -MArray::Transpose -F'\|' -lane '
    push @a, [@F]
    } END {print for map {join " ", @$_} transpose(\@a)
' <<END
DelayTimeThreshold|MaxDelayPerMinute|Name
10000|5|rca
END
```

```
DelayTimeThreshold 10000
MaxDelayPerMinute 5
Name rca
```

Answer (score 0):

As a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict; 
use Data::Dumper;

my $file1 = ('DelayTimeThreshold|MaxDelayPerMinute|Name');
my $file2 = ('10000|5|rca');

my @file1 = split('\|', $file1);
my @file2 = split('\|', $file2);

my %hash;

@hash{@file1} = @file2;

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Name' => 'rca',
          'DelayTimeThreshold' => '10000',
          'MaxDelayPerMinute' => '5'
        };
```

OR:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $#file1; $i++) {
    print "$file1[$i] $file2[$i]\n";
}
```

Output:

```
DelayTimeThreshold 10000
MaxDelayPerMinute 5
Name rca
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a file that contains a single header row with column names, followed by multiple detail rows with column values, for example,

```
DelayTimeThreshold|MaxDelayPerMinute|Name
10000|5|abc
20001|6|def
30002|7|ghk
40003|8|jkl
50004|9|mnp
```

The following code would print that file, using the names from the first row, paired with values from each subsequent (detail) row,

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my ($fn,$fh)=("header.csv"); #whatever the file is named...
open($fh,"< $fn") || error "cannot open $fn";
my ($count,$line,@names,@vals)=(0);
while(<$fh>)
{
    chomp $_;
    @vals=split(/\|/,$_);
    if($count++<1) { @names=@vals; next; } #first line is names
    for (my $ndx=0; $ndx<=$#names; $ndx++) { #print each
        print "$names[$ndx] $vals[$ndx]\n";
    }
}
```

Suppose you want to keep around each row, annotated with names, in an array,

```
my %row;
my @records;
while(<$fh>)
{
    chomp $_;
    @vals=split(/\|/,$_);
    if($count++<1) { @names=@vals; next; }
    @row{@names} = @vals;
    push(@records,\%row);
}
```

Maybe you want to refer to the rows by some key column,

```
my %row;
my %records;
while(<$fh>)
{
    chomp $_;
    @vals=split(/\|/,$_);
    if($count++<1) { @names=@vals; next; }
    @row{@names} = @vals;
    $records{$vals[0]}=\%row;
}
```